# In ipython, how to get a list of all local variables of a specific type and with a pattern?

Tags: python, local-variables

For example, I have created 5 `pd.DataFrame`s in the working space, which are:

```
trade_i = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 2))
trade_xt = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 2))
trade_mmt = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 2))
trade_pg = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 2))
trade_fg = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 2))
```

As you can see, the types are all `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`, and startswith `trade_`:

```
type(trade_fg)
Out[508]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

So, how can I return a list of them? not just returning the name of the variables in a list.

So far, I can get the names of the variables startswtih `trade_` in a list like this:

```
df_list = [x for x in dir() if x.startswith('trade_')]
df_list
Out[514]: 
['trade_i',
 'trade_xt',
 'trade_mmt',
 'trade_pg',
 'trade_fg']
```

But this is not what I want.
And by the way, the reason that I want to return these dataFrame variables in a list is to append one column for each of them.

Comment: Don't do this. Use a dictionary.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I don't get it. You mean in the way I created the 5 `DataFrame`s or returning them in a dictionary? What's the key and value for this dict? And I kind of felt that the way I created 5 variables could be done more efficiently, too. Not just typing the similar statement 5 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval()` to receive the reference of the variable by its name and use `isinstance()` to check whether it is a `DataFrame` like this:

```
[eval(v) for v in dir() 
 if isinstance(eval(v), pd.DataFrame) and v.startswith('trade_')]
```

As suggested, you might want to create a dictionary - except you don't need that name information. In that case a list will be good enough:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([4,5,6])
trade_df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])

data_frames = dict([(v, eval(v)) for v in dir() 
                    if isinstance(eval(v), pd.DataFrame) and v.startswith('trade_')])
```

Answer (score 1):

since you are using only strings that you yourself created it is safe to use `eval` to get their value:

```
local_trade_variables = {x:eval(x) for x in dir() if x.startswith('trade_')}
```

to make a dictionary of name to value

or you can use `locals()` directly without `dir()` which is **already** a dictionary of the local variables:

```
local_trade_variables = {key:val for key,val in locals().items() if key.startswith('trade_')}
```